# extJS from scratch: the installation guide

Tags: apache, extjs, installation

I'm trying to dive into extJS. I've spent some time by reading some manuals and watching videos, but I'm a little bit confused. What's the list of the software that should be installed on my Windows 7 to use extJS. Should I install SDK? Should I install Apache? Is XAMPP an option?
I'm using Windows 7.
All I have now is the downloaded extJS installation archive.
Also, as far as I know, using IntelliJ IDEA with extJS is an option.

I really appreciate if anyone can show me a list of the required software for Windows 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you don't technically need Sencha Cmd to create an app, you will need it to build the application for production.

So, the bare minimum of what I would suggest is:

- ExtJS 4.2.1
- Sencha Cmd (latest version)

Re: Apache vs. IIS, that's completely up to you, and has more to do with whatever stack you'll want to run ExtJS under than with anything related to actually using ExtJS. I use it with both IIS and Apache, depending on whether I'm at work (IIS) or home (Apache).